# NetSuite Saved Search Formula for Depreciation Dates

Tags: sql, netsuite, saved-searches

I need help creating a saved search in NetSuite, but I'm not sure how to use their formulas.

Some fixed assets were somehow imported incorrectly and have depreciation history records dating all the way back to 1980. So in my search I need to use a formula that will return 1 if the depreciation history date is before the acquisition date (or depreciation start date, whichever works), or 0 if not.

Can anyone help create this formula?

I tried creating a formula, and it would not accept the formula at all or work to filter the saved search.

Answer (score 0):

Use formula currency/date/text/numeric according to calculation.

**In Result Tab**-

Formula (Numeric)  | Summary Type- Sum (Its optional)

Formula-  case when to_char({depreciationDateFieldId},'mm/yyyy') < to_char({acquisitionDateFieldId},'mm/yyyy') then 1 else 0 end

**In Criteria Tab-**
Use like this

Formula (Numeric), use formula as see the image:-

[Criteria tab formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEhGh.png)

Note- Use all fiedlds in lower case.